# div on 3 columns using float

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place 6 divs with different height on 3 columns.

I use float property for divs on the left and on the right and margin: 0 auto for central divs.

Using clear property I placed second row of divs under the first one, but I want each div is under the div with the same float option without blank space between them.

Instead they are aligned the lowest div.

Here's the fiddle: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lbc5pq7/1/)

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left-top</div>
<div class="right">right-top</div>
<div class="left" style="clear:left">left-bottom</div>
<div class="right" style="clear:right">right-bottom</div>
<div class="center">center-top</div>
<div class="center">center-bottom</div>
```

Thanks for help,

Piero.

Comment: Can you change the html order? https://jsfiddle.net/8Lbc5pq7/2/

Comment: You can really spare yourself a lot of work by using [flexible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) [box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout

Comment: You can also create a 3-column layout having 2 blocks in each column.

Comment: can you please show final output image

Comment: If you can't change the order of the elements, and you can't use flexbox, you could relatively position the bottom-right box with a negative top equal to the difference in height between left-top and right-top. Just be aware of overlap issues should the boxes expand due to content.

Comment: boxes are filled dinamically, they may have heights different from what I used.
Can you do an example using flexbox?

Comment: @PieroVirgilio check DaniP 's fiddle above... maybe that is what you need...

Comment: @DaniP and kukkuz
If i set height:30px to .left class I obtain the same situation but on the other side.
Height of boxes is dynamic in my real case, the fiddle is only a simple example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them in 3 columns/DIVs 33.33% wide which you float:

https://jsfiddle.net/8Lbc5pq7/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="column">
<div class="left">left-top</div>
<div class="left">left-bottom</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="center">center-top</div>
<div class="center">center-bottom</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
<div class="right">right-top</div>
<div class="right" style="clear:right">right-bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 95%;
}
.column {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
}

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one.

Html Code

```
<div class="left">left-top</div>
<div class="right">right-top</div>
<div class="left">left-bottom</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="right">right-bottom</div>
<div class="center">center-top</div>
<div class="center">center-bottom</div>
```

Css Code

```
.left, .right, .center {border: 1px solid red;width: 30%;margin:2px;}
.clearfix{clear:both;}
.left {float:left;}
.right { float:left;}
.center {float:left;}
```

check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Dhavalr/9cyq8tu9/

Answer (score 0):

try using this style:

```
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}



.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. 
This solution only removes space between left divs and central divs

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code

<style>
 div {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  width: 33.1%;
 }
.left {
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  float:left;
  height: 50px;
}
</style>
<div class="left">left-top</div>
<div class="center">center-top</div>
<div class="right">right-top</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<div class="left" style="clear:left;">left-bottom</div>
<div class="center">center-bottom</div>
<div class="right" style="clear:right;">right-bottom</div>
```